# Should we have a tag for command-oriented interfaces/architecture?

Tags: feature-request

There is a lot of talk lately about command oriented interface/ architecture and I am wondering if we should have a tag for the command oriented subjects to properly classify these questions?

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandOrientedInterface.html

Comment: Do you have specific example questions where that tag would be useful? Tags don't get created just for the sake of creating a tag, they're created when specific questions need them.

Comment: Why would anyone today want a tag for a human-interface from the 1960's? :)

Comment: Huh? I mean this: 
http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandOrientedInterface.html

Comment: @Mat Well, yeah. I asked a question about it after reading articles about the subject. I see this being used with PHP rather often. I am planning to make use of it myself.